How to find what causes "uci: Invalid argument"
When installing any package, I see an warning message from uci:
uci: Invalid argument

How can I find where the error is?
Note: This is only warning message.  The package still installs successfully.

Confirm the error by running:
uci export 2>&1 | grep 'uci:'

If it finds an error inside a uci config file, it will show "Parse error".  In that case, you can find the file name using strace.
If uci export says uci: Invalid argument, then it is not a parse error inside a config file.  Instead, it may mean that uci does not like the name of one of the files in the /etc/config directory.

"It is important to know that UCI identifiers and config file
names may contain only the characters a-z, 0-9 and _. E.g. no hyphens
(-) are allowed."
-- OpenWRT mailing list / wiki

I found that filenames which contain both a period and a hyphen, e.g. "network.old-version", can cause the error uci: Invalid argument.
To find this error, try looking for file names in /etc/config which contain a character which is not a-z, 0-9, _, or -.
You cannot use strace to find the problematic file name, because of technical reasons.  Hint: readdir() is not a system call.
If you cannot find a bad file name, then perhaps the error message indicates a failed system call.  You might find the system call that failed if you know how to use strace.
Sidenote: Does it always cause an error if there is a hyphen (-) in the name of a file in /etc/config ?
Currently, filenames which contain a hyphen can be created automatically during an upgrade, e.g. "/etc/config/network-opkg".  Such files appear to have no special treatment.  This means you can run uci export network-opkg, uci get network-opkg.@device[0].name, etc.  It also means the "network-opkg" file does not affect anything, because there is no service that reads a uci "package" called "network-opkg".
If a file name contain hyphens, but not a period character, it does not seem to cause an error.  Although, the way OpenWRT works here could be confusing.
